# Error: name 's' is not defined

Tags: python

I have defined s as a list but when I run the module it says s is not defined.

```
def contains(s, sub):
    s = ["apples", "bananas", "oranges", "watermelon", "apricots"]

    sub = raw_input("Please enter a substring of s: ")

    if sub in s:
        print sub, "is a substring of s."
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    contains(s, sub)
```

Comment: I really like those questions. They serve as free lucky points. Man, you should mail me before you ask, I'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `s` in the last line:

```
contains(s, sub)
```

This is *outside* of the function, and you didn't define a global `s`. `s` exists only as a local name *inside* of the function. The same applies to `sub`.

Move the definition of the list and `sub` to that section:

```
def contains(s, sub):
    if sub in s:
        print sub, "is a substring of s."
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = ["apples", "bananas", "oranges", "watermelon", "apricots"]
    sub = raw_input("Please enter a substring of s: ")
    contains(s, sub)
```

You could use different names too and leave the printing outside of the function:

```
def contains(s, sub):
    return sub in s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fruits = ["apples", "bananas", "oranges", "watermelon", "apricots"]
    substring = raw_input("Please enter a substring of fruits: ")
    if contains(fruits, substring):
        print substring, "is a substring of fruits."
```

and the function will still use `s` and `sub` as local names.

Answer (score 2):

`s` is only defined within the function `contains`. `s` is bound to the parameter that is passed into the function. In other words, you are calling the function incorrectly. You probably want to do this:

```
def contains(s, sub):
    return sub in s

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = ["apples", "bananas", "oranges", "watermelon", "apricots"]
    sub = raw_input("Please enter a substring of s: ")
    if contains(s, sub):
        print sub, "is a substring of s."
```

Answer (score 0):

In the piece of code here

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    contains(s, sub)
```

You've not defined `s` as a variable.

You should define `s` as a list inside the main function as well before you call `contains` using the reference of `s`.

The differences between the variable `s` in the `main` function and in the `contains` function is that they're totally two different variables. You may want to check what a [parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29) is